# Firefox WebIDE port requirements on a corporate Network

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to remote debug an Android device running Firefox using the Firefox WebIDE. I have tested this and it works well in our lab.
At a client location controlled by a third party networking company it is not working.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_over_WiFi

I have observed that the Firefox browser on Android will register itself to a server out on the internet, and the PC running the WebIDE will do the same when it is looking for possible devices to debug.

Using a testing tool I can see UDP packets being sent. It appears that it is these packets which allow the device to show up in the WI-FI DEVICES section in the WebIDE, and then can be selected. Once selected you can see the PC attempt the connection to the Android device.

So the problem here appears to be that without that access to the internet the PC WebIDE can not "see" the Android device.

Question #1

So the question is what are the port/protocol requirements which must be in place so that the WebIDE is able to successfully connect to an Android device running Firefox in a corporate environment.

Note: This is NOT a phone, it is only an Android device connect via WiFi, so it does not automatically have access to the world outside its local network. The PC doing the debugging is also behind a firewall and not opened to the outside world. I need to tell the networking folks exactly what needs to be opened in order to get this working.

Question #2

Is there a better place to ask this question? The team which develops Firefox and/ or Firefox WebIDE?

I have searched the internet high and low for an answer for this but have found nothing on specific requirements which must be in place to make this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is what are the port/protocol requirements which must be in place so that the WebIDE is able to successfully connect to an Android device running Firefox in a corporate environment.

That's a good question!  It's true that these requirements were not listed anyway clearly.  I have just updated the [troubleshooting page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE/Troubleshooting#Connecting_to_Firefox_for_Android_over_Wi-Fi) to list them, and I am pasting it below as well:

Some Wi-Fi networks may block the packets used for Wi-Fi device discovery. Check with your network administrator to make sure these actions are allowed:

- The computer and the Android device must be able to send and receive UDP multicast packets sent on ports 50624-50625 to multicast address 224.0.0.115
- The network router must support UDP multicast packets
- Routers will not forward these UDP multicast packets, so effectively this means both devices need to be speaking directly to the same router without any other hops in between

The devices should not need access to the general Internet during this process, but admittedly there has not been as much testing of that to make sure of it.

> Is there a better place to ask this question? The team which develops Firefox and/ or Firefox WebIDE?

The [DevTools Discourse forum](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/c/devtools) is a good place to ask questions like this.  It is actively watched by engineers on the DevTools team.